# create function for make upcase for backward word in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm newbie to create lisp functions in EMACS. 
I want to make function to make backward word in uppercase.
M-u does make uppercase for forward word, but I want to do it in backwardly.
Also I want to put cursor at the end of word after doing the function.
And I want to M-u does this function, not the original function.
How should I write a function in Emacs lisp?

thanks.

Comment: Note that typing `M- - M-c` will do that with only 2 keystrokes.

Comment: I think @Juancho means `M--` `M-u`.  The author mentioned `M-u` in the question so presumably they want the whole word uppercased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that upcases the previous word is

```
(defun upcase-previous-word ()
  (interactive)
  (upcase-word -1))
```

If you want more information on function `upcase-word`, try `M-x describe-function` then `upcase-word`. This assigns `M-u` to it

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-u") 'upcase-previous-word)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What should I do if I want to upcase characters backward until I meet a white space?

Answer (score 0):

I have some functions I wrote to provide this functionality as I couldn't find anything built-in that operated on multiple words. They might prove useful:

```
(defun my-get-words-left (number-of-words)
  (save-excursion
    (backward-word number-of-words)
    (point)))

(defun my-reformat-left-uppercase (number-of-words)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((region-end (point))
        (region-start (my-get-words-left number-of-words)))
    (upcase-region region-start region-end)))
```

Note that this won't put you at the end of a word, but to add that functionality shouldn't be too hard.

Edit: actually, now I remember there is actually a built-in way of doing it too:

```
(upcase-word n)
```

Giving a negative number to upcase-word will convert backwards by that number of words, leaving point where it is (as in my function). I haven't messed around with it since I accidentally reinvented the wheel before I was aware.